# mypy: creating a type that accepts list of instances of subclasses

Tags: python, mypy

Suppose I have a `Child` class that is a subclass of `Parent` class, and a function that accepts a list of instances of `Parent` subclasses:

```
from typing import List


class Parent:
    pass


class Child(Parent):
    pass


def func(objects: List[Parent]) -> None:
    print(objects)


children = [Child()]
func(children)
```

running `mypy` on this produces an error:

```
 error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "List[Child]"; expected "List[Parent]"
```

How do I create a type for this?

P.S. There's a way to fix this particular error with a `Sequence` type:

```
def func(objects: Sequence[Parent]) -> None:
    print(objects)
```

but this doesn't help in other similar cases. I need a `List`, not a `Sequence`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Passing in a list here is fundamentally not type-safe. For example, what if you do this?

```
def func(objects: List[Parent]) -> None:
    print(objects)
    objects.append(Parent())

children: List[Child] = [Child(), Child(), Child()]
func(children)
# Uh-oh! 'children' contains a Parent()!
```

If this were permitted to type check, your code would end up containing a bug.

To use type-jargon, `List` is intentionally designed to be an *invariant* type. That is, even though `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`, it is not the case that `List[Child]` is a subtype of `List[Parent]`, or vice-versa. You can find more info about invariance [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types) and [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance).

The most common alternative is to use `Sequence` instead, which is a read-only interface/protocol/whatever. And since Sequence is read-only, it's safe for it to be *covariant*: that is, `Sequence[Child]` is considered to be a valid subtype of `Sequence[Parent]`.

Depending on what exactly you're doing, you may be able to use [type variables](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#type-variables-with-upper-bounds) instead. E.g. instead of saying "this function takes in a list of Parent", you say "this function takes in a list of any class which is Parent, or a subclass of Parent":

```
TParent = TypeVar('TParent', bound=Parent)

def func(objects: List[TParent]) -> List[TParent]:
    print(objects)

    # Would not typecheck: we can't assume 'objects' will be a List[Parent]
    objects.append(Parent())  

    return objects
```

Depending on what exactly you're doing, you could maaaaaaaaybe create a [custom Protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocols.html) that defines a write-only list-like collection (or a custom data structure). And since your data structure would be write-only, you could make it *contravariant* -- that is, `WriteOnlyThing[Parent]` would be a subtype of `WriteOnlyThing[Child]`. You then make `func` accept `WriteOnlyThing[Child]` and could safely pass in instances of both `WriteOnlyThing[Child]` and `WriteOnlyThing[Parent]`.

If neither approach works in your case, your only recourse is to either use `# type: ignore` to silence the error (not recommended), give up on type-checking the contents of the list and make the argument of type `List[Any]` (also not recommended), or figure out how to restructure your code so it's type-safe.

Comment: To make it type-safe you can also use `Tuple` instead of `List`. You cannot append to tuple, so the problem described by @Michael0x2a is gone.

Comment: @pawelswiecki -- you could use a tuple, sure, or any covariant data structure, but I don't think using Tuple in this case really buys you much vs using Sequence in this case. Tuple is a subclass of Sequence, and adds only a few additional tuple-specific methods such as `__lt__`, none of which I believe are also implemented by lists. If OP's original code was using lists, they were using any of these tuple-specific methods to begin with. So why not go with the more general type and just use Sequence?

Comment: If tuple is ok (hard to tell without more context) I'd use with it, since it's much simpler than using `TypeVar`. (List does implement `__lt__`, at least you can compare lists.)

Comment: Typevar is exactly what i was looking for. I saw the docs, just was't able to wrap my head around the "upper bound" concept. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael0x2a please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316262/mypy-and-attrs-errors-typechecking-lists-of-subclasses , it is an extended, full version of my problem with all the context. Thanks a lot!